# eb labs download not working in some AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-server, ebcli

I am new to dealing with the Parse-Server and hosting on AWS. But I have noticed that the "eb labs download" command in terminal works when my Parse Server environment is in N.Virginia but comes back with a whole list of errors when the the server environment was initially kept in Oregon. The errors are pertaining to "HTTP header errors". Anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance! Error is below:

```
Downloading application version...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebcore.py", line 150, in main
    app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 797, in run
    return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py", line 57, in default
    self.do_command()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/labs/download.py", line 36, in do_command
    download_source_bundle(app_name, env_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/labs/download.py", line 49, in download_source_bundle
    data = s3.get_object(bucket_name, key_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/s3.py", line 68, in get_object
    Key=key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/s3.py", line 34, in _make_api_call
    return aws.make_api_call('s3', operation_name, **operation_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 218, in make_api_call
    response_data = operation(**operation_options)
  File "/Users/Home/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 251, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/Home/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 526, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/Users/Home/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 141, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/Users/Home/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 170, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/Users/Home/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 249, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/Users/Home/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/Home/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/Home/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 868, in redirect_from_error
    new_region = self.get_bucket_region(bucket, response)
  File "/Users/Home/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 913, in get_bucket_region
    response_headers = service_response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']
KeyError: 'HTTPHeaders'
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show the errors.

Comment: Have edited the question - thanks Michael

Answer (score 0):

Generally the EB CLI works in a single region at a time. If you have a specific region in which you want to use you can specify it using the `--region` flag.

```
 eb labs download --region us-west-2
```

Otherwise it is usually best practice to keep your AWS stack resources in a single region.